# SQL query get all duplicate records with count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with duplicate data in a certain column (`state`). I need to fetch all rows and also display the `COUNT()` of duplicate records.

#### Sample Data

```
name     state  email
----     ----   -----
john     ny     john@ny.com
smith    ny     smith@ny.com
bryan    nj     bryan@nj.com
```

I need to write a SQL query to display records like this, that includes the number of duplicate `state` values on each row:

```
name     state  email         count
----     ----   -----         -------
john     ny     john@ny.com      2
smith    ny     smith@ny.com     2
bryan    nj     bryan@nj.com     1
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: Are you looking for a MySQL solution or a Microsoft SQL Server solution? You've tagged both RDBM systems.

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: Thanks Everyone. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a `COUNT(*)` over the `State` `PARTITION`:

```
Select  name, state, email,
        Count(*) Over (Partition By State) As Count
From    YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (name varchar(5), state varchar(2), email varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (name, state, email)
VALUES
    ('john', 'ny', 'john@ny.com'),
    ('smith', 'ny', 'smith@ny.com'),
    ('bryan', 'nj', 'bryan@nj.com')
;
```

Script

**SQL SERVER** :

```
 select  name,state,email,COUNT(state)OVER(PARTITION BY state  )Cnt from @Table1
```

**MySQL**

```
Select T.name, T.state, T.email,TT.cnt from @Table1 T
INNER JOIN (select COUNT(state)cnt,state from @Table1
GROUP BY state)TT
ON T.state = TT.state
ORDER BY cnt Desc
```

Comment: welcome @user2459457 if it is useful tick mark it as right answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do with a from on the aggregate

```
        select state, count, b.name, b.email from 
        ( select a.state as state , a.count(*) as count
        from my_table as a 
        group by a.state ) t 
        inner join my_table as b on b.state = t.state
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the display you presented:

```
SELECT name ,
       [state] ,
       email, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY state) as [count]
       FROM myTable
       ORDER BY [state] DESC;
```